Is the understanding of the Chinese characters ‘房’ and ‘屋’ correct?
In Chinese, the words ‘房’ and ‘屋’ are synonyms. For example, the Chinese sentence ‘小明在房里’ should be equal to ‘小明在屋里’. However, the sentence: ‘快看，那有一间房’ is not equal to ‘快看，那里有一间屋’. My understanding is that the Chinese character ‘屋’ is mainly used for the interior of a building, while the Chinese character ‘房’ is mainly used for the exterior of a building as a whole. I am not sure if my understanding is correct.

屋 the entire house; 房 the entire house or a room, as in 房間.

房 usually refers to a room in a house
屋 usually refers to a house
A house may have one or more rooms.
A room must be in a house.
Therefore, ‘小明在房裡’; he is in one of the rooms (of this house), so he must be in this house!
However, ‘小明在屋裡’; he may be in the living room, not in the bedroom. Therefore, he might NOT in the room.
In Chinese, the living-"room" is a public place and is not considered a private "room"(房).
Generally speaking, a place with a door that can block others can be called a 房.
古者宮室之制，前堂後室。前堂之兩頭有夾室，後室之兩旁有東西房
Ancient style, front hall堂 , back room室.
There are mezzanine rooms夾室 at both ends of the front hall
There are east and west rooms房 on both sides of the back room後室.
But, even rest-"room" has a door,and very private... but it's too small to sleep inside, so it's NOT a room(房), again. :D
Actually, rest-"room" is named 洗手間, small then a 房.
Like cloak-"room", it's a small place where cloaks, cloths and quilts are put together, not for sleeping, it's call 衣帽"間", not 房.

‘屋’ is mainly used for the interior of a building, while the Chinese character ‘房’ is mainly used for the exterior of a building as a whole

This may be completely reversed.
--

If you are standing outside the house, and saw 小明 is standing in the living-room from window. You'll say 小明在屋裡.
BUT! 小明在房裡 is incorrect here. Because he is NOT in any one of room.
If you are standing outside the house, and saw 小明 is sleeping in the bedroom from window. You'll say 小明在房裡.
小明在屋裡 is correct too!  Because a room is a part of this house.


This is not a good question as 房 and 屋 (I should say most of Chinese characters) should not be talked individually in modern Chinese. Modern Chinese is word-based, not character-based. If you see characters alone, the context is very important.
In addition to that, I can always find counter examples of what you said:

两房一卫：2 bedroom and 2 bathroom
屋脊：ridge of a house
屋舍：house


房子 is not equal to 房间。
房子指整个建筑(比如某一户人家居住的地方)，房间是某一个人住的地方(比如某人的卧室)。
Example：那栋房子有3个屋 is not equal to 那栋房子有3个房间。


‘屋’ is mainly used for the interior of a building, while the Chinese character ‘房’ is mainly used for the exterior of a building as a whole.

No, it is incorrect. See examples below.
Exterior building components:

屋頂 = 房頂; 屋簷 = 房簷; 屋基 = 房基

Interior building components:

屋樑 = 房樑; 屋柱 = 房柱

Buildings as a whole:

屋子 = 房子; 屋宇 = 房舍

